# Auto Completing JCombobox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

I am developing a java based software connected with a mysql database. I have an Item table in my database. I created a bean class which can keep all item data with it and. Then  I loaded each Item data in to its object and fill a Jcombobox. Now I want to search with Item name and get all Item data when selecting that item. I have overidden the toString method to Item name in that class. Is there any way to search my Item objects inside a jcombobox? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, swingx provides an auto-completion feature: https://swingx.java.net/

Comment: where is the link for Auto-completion?

Comment: What do you mean with "link for Auto-completion"? The link I've provided mentions auto-completion. The old documentation seems to missing on the "new" java.net site, though.

Comment: Here is a link to some old Javadocs. http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/package-summary.html
 The latest version is 1.6.5-1 AFAIK.